# How do I generate a response file to be used with apt-get or aptitude?

Tags: debian, puppet, apt, exim, aptitude

I need to install exim4 through puppet. Because this installation requires interactive configuration, I need a response file, but I don't know how to generate one. So, how do I generate a response file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [debconf-set-selections](http://man.he.net/man1/debconf-set-selections) to pre-populate the configuration database before you run apt-get.  You can use debconf-get-selections (in debconf-utils) on a configured system to see what needs to be set.  Also keep in mind that with exim, the package you actually need to configure is exim4-config.

```
debconf-get-selections | grep exim4-config
exim4-config    exim4/dc_noalias_regenerate boolean false
exim4-config    exim4/dc_smarthost  string  
...
```

See also http://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed

Comment: Actually, I had to create the group `Debian-exim` before running the installation. This got me stuck for a while, but it's just a peculiarity of exim installation.

Comment: if you want to see what the possible values are for a package, just do the following... `sudo debconf-get-selections | grep exim`.  More details at [Fully automated ubuntu server setups using preseed](http://www.rndguy.ca/2010/02/24/fully-automated-ubuntu-server-setups-using-preseed/)